Elixir Ecto: A guide/help to impore this big query with multiple join using Limit
I have this big query, where I am loading many relations
customers_query =
  from customers in Customer, as: :customer,
    left_join: custom_field_answers in CustomFieldAnswer,
    on: customers.id == custom_field_answers.customer_id,
    left_join: custom_field_for_answer in CustomField,
    on: custom_field_for_answer.id == custom_field_answers.custom_field_id,
    left_join: seeker_company in Company,
    on: seeker_company.id == customers.seeker_company_id,
    left_join: received_references in VendorReference,
    on: seeker_company.id == received_references.target_company_id,
    left_join: finicity_account_projections in NectarineCredit.Financials.FinicityAccountProjection,
    on: seeker_company.id == finicity_account_projections.company_id and is_nil(finicity_account_projections.deleted_at),
    left_join: manual_institutions in NectarineCredit.Financials.ManualInstitution,
    on: seeker_company.id == manual_institutions.company_id and is_nil(manual_institutions.deleted_at),
    left_join: accounts in NectarineCredit.Financials.ManualAccount,
    on: manual_institutions.id == accounts.institution_id and is_nil(accounts.deleted_at),
    left_join: internal_bank_documents in NectarineCredit.Financials.InternalBankDocument,
    on: accounts.id == internal_bank_documents.manual_account_id,
    left_join: pending_vr_invites in Referral,
    on:
      pending_vr_invites.from_company_id == seeker_company.id and
        pending_vr_invites.type == :vendor_reference and
        pending_vr_invites.complete == false and pending_vr_invites.source == 0 and is_nil(pending_vr_invites.deleted_at),
    where: customers.provider_company_id == ^current_company_id,
    where: is_nil(customers.deleted_at),
    preload: [
      custom_field_answers: {custom_field_answers, custom_field: custom_field_for_answer},
      seeker_company:
        {seeker_company,
         received_references: received_references, referrals: pending_vr_invites, finicity_account_projections: finicity_account_projections, manual_institutions: {manual_institutions, accounts: {accounts, internal_bank_documents: internal_bank_documents}}},
      applications: ^(&preload_application/1)
    ]

most of the relations are has_many on each other, this query works fine and returns 533 records which is an accurate number, but when I try to put a limit on that query such as limit: 20 it gives only 2 records.
Also the preload_application looks like this.
  defp most_recent_application() do
    NectarineCredit.Credit.Application
    |> select([app], %{id: app.id, row_number: over(row_number(), :customer_id_partition)})
    |> windows([_], [customer_id_partition: [partition_by: :customer_id, order_by: [desc: :inserted_at]]])
  end

  defp most_recent_agreement() do
    NectarineCredit.Credit.Agreement
    |> select([agreement], %{id: agreement.id, row_number: over(row_number(), :application_id_partition)})
    |> windows([_], [application_id_partition: [partition_by: :application_id, order_by: [desc: :inserted_at]]])
  end

  defp preload_application(_) do
    NectarineCredit.Credit.Application
    |> join(:inner, [app], rc in subquery(most_recent_application()),
      on: app.id == rc.id and rc.row_number == 1
    )
    |> join(:left, [app, _rc], user in NectarineCredit.Accounts.User, on: app.last_updated_by_id == user.id)
    |> preload([app, _rc, user, agreement], [last_updated_by: user, agreements: ^(&preload_agreement/1)])
    |> Repo.all()
  end

  defp preload_agreement(_) do
    NectarineCredit.Credit.Agreement
    |> join(:inner, [agreement], rc in subquery(most_recent_agreement()),
      on: agreement.id == rc.id and rc.row_number == 1
    )
    |> Repo.all()
  end

Although the query still works fine without limit, I still do think that I am not doing the join accurately, is left_joins are good approach here?
The query is returning data to the GraphQL query, are there any better ways to solve it?
any help or guide would be appreciated Thank you.

You haven't provided and example of how you're applying the limit, but I'd guess it's being applied to one of the joins rather than the query itself. Try adding this line: customers_query = from customers_query, limit: 20.
